# The Request URL is being called twice when using URLRewrite Filter

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using Tuckey URL Rewrite filter. I have installed it on my Google App Engine (Java). and it is working well besides one annoying thing. Apparently when the request URL is re-written and handled by the controller a new request is being issued with no parameters to the same controller. This happens after the HTTP response has been returned from the first call.

I have copied the basic configuration I read on the site and did not change it much.

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Tuckey URL Rewrite filter is working properly.
I had an issue with jQuery UI Tabs which issue the request twice.